# Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed

Tags: vba, excel

**Problem:**

Variable not storing correctly. After running the code, I used the debugger to figure out what was wrong. The variable `setRow` is not storing any values. Thus, throwing an error.

**Code:**

```
Public Sub initData(index As Integer)
' ws = COE Monthly Report
' ws2 = FormattedRaw
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COE Monthly Report")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FormattedRaw")
Dim setRow As Integer
Dim countryRow As String
countryRow = ws2.Range("E" & index)
Select Case ws2.Range("A" & index)
Case ws2.Range("A" & index) = "AR"
    Select Case countryRow
        Case countryRow = "Australia"
            setRow = 7
        Case countryRow = "New Zealand"
            setRow = 8
        Case countryRow = "Singapore"
            setRow = 9
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
Case ws2.Range("A" & index) = "HW"
    Select Case countryRow
        Case countryRow = "Australia"
            row = 11
        Case countryRow = "New Zealand"
            row = 12
        Case countryRow = "Philippines"
            row = 13
        Case countryRow = "Malaysia"
            row = 14
        Case countryRow = "Singapore"
            row = 15
        Case countryRow = "Thailand"
            row = 16
        Case countryRow = "Vietnam"
            row = 17
        Case countryRow = "Indonesia"
            row = 18
        Case countryRow = "India"
            row = 19
        Case countryRow = "Korea"
            row = 20
        Case countryRow = "Taiwan"
            row = 21
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
Case ws2.Range("A" & index) = "PBS"
    Select Case countryRow
        Case countryRow = "Australia"
            row = 23
        Case countryRow = "New Zealand"
            row = 24
        Case countryRow = "Philippines"
            row = 25
        Case countryRow = "Malaysia"
            row = 26
        Case countryRow = "Singapore"
            row = 27
        Case countryRow = "Thailand"
            row = 28
        Case countryRow = "Vietnam"
            row = 29
        Case countryRow = "Indonesia"
            row = 30
        Case countryRow = "Korea"
            row = 31
        Case countryRow = "Taiwan"
            row = 32
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
Case ws2.Range("A" & index) = "SWG"
    Select Case countryRow
        Case countryRow = "Australia"
            row = 34
        Case countryRow = "New Zealand"
            row = 35
        Case countryRow = "Philippines"
            row = 36
        Case countryRow = "Malaysia"
            row = 37
        Case countryRow = "Singapore"
            row = 38
        Case countryRow = "Thailand"
            row = 39
        Case countryRow = "Vietnam"
            row = 40
        Case countryRow = "Indonesia"
            row = 41
        Case countryRow = "Indonesia"
            row = 42
        Case countryRow = "Korea"
            row = 43
        Case countryRow = "Taiwan"
            row = 44
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
Case ws2.Range("A" & index) = "TSS"
    Select Case countryRow
        Case countryRow = "Singapore"
            row = 46
        Case countryRow = "Malaysia"
            row = 47
        Case countryRow = "Vietnam"
            row = 48
        Case countryRow = "Philippines"
            row = 49
        Case countryRow = "Indonesia"
            row = 50
        Case countryRow = "Thailand"
            row = 51
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Select
' ~~ If control point type is 'KCFR'
If ws2.Range("L" & index) = "KCFR" Then
    ' ~~ Populate Tested Samples KCFR in COE Monthly Updated
    ws.Range("D" & setRow) = ws.Range("D" & setRow) + 1
    If ws2.Range("AG" & setRow) <> "0" Then
        ' ~~ Populate Defects in KCFR in COE Monthly Updated
        ws.Range("E" & setRow) = ws.Range("E" & setRow) + 1
    End If
' ~~ If control point type is 'KCO'
ElseIf ws2.Range("L" & index) = "KCO" Then
    ' ~~ Populate Tested Samples KCO in COE Monthly Updated
    ws.Range("G" & setRow) = ws.Range("G" & setRow) + 1
    If ws2.Range("AG" & setRow) <> "0" Then
        ' ~~ Populate Defects in KCO in COE Monthly Updated
        ws.Range("H" & setRow) = ws.Range("H" & setRow) + 1
    End If
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Note:

I only used the first `CASE` statement for testing. So you can see variables declared as `row` but it's just the same as `setRow`.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Does your code work when column A contains `"AR"`?  If so, I would suggest that you need to change `row` to `setRow`.  (And **please** use `Option Explicit`!  That would have highlighted the typo, and saved a question.)

Comment: @YowE3K yeah, it works but when going to the inner case, I checked if the country is `"Australia"`, the `setRow` does not store a value of 7 at all.

Comment: Your `Select Case` statement shouldn't be `Case ws2.Range("A" & index) = "AR"` - use `Case "AR"` and `Case countryRow = "Australia"` should be just `Case "Australia"`  Currently your Select Case is trying to see if countryrow is the same text as "Australia=Australia".

Comment: You aren't setting `setRow` for Australia except for "AR", you are setting `row`.  As I said, change `row` to `setRow`.  And include `Option Explicit` as the first line of your code module to prevent typos like this.

Comment: Ohh - no - you also have a problem with `countryRow = "Australia"` - that should just be `"Australia"`.  Sorry, missed that one before.

Comment: @YowE3K `Option Explicit` is invalid inside a procedure. Yeah, I changed that already. Same error :(

Comment: `Option Explicit` should be put as the first line of the **code module**, i.e. before any `Function` or `Sub` or `Dim` or `Private` or `Public` or `Const` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Select Case` statement syntax is wrong, and you also can't type `setRow`.

An example of what one of your `Select Case` statements should look like would be (including the correction of `row` to `setRow`):

```
Select Case countryRow
    Case "Australia"
        setRow = 11
    Case "New Zealand"
        setRow = 12
    Case "Philippines"
        setRow = 13
    Case "Malaysia"
        setRow = 14
    Case "Singapore"
        setRow = 15
    Case "Thailand"
        setRow = 16
    Case "Vietnam"
        setRow = 17
    Case "Indonesia"
        setRow = 18
    Case "India"
        setRow = 19
    Case "Korea"
        setRow = 20
    Case "Taiwan"
        setRow = 21
    Case Else
        Exit Sub
End Select
```

Comment: a newbie mistake :( Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put the following to your code:

```
Debug.Print ws2.Range("A" & index)
Select Case ws2.Range("A" & index)
Stop
Case ws2.Range("A" & index) = "AR"
```

Once you stop, take a look at the immediate window to see the value of `ws2.Range("A" & index)` based on it `setRow` is assigned.

Comment: it throws a compile error. `Statements and labels invalid between Select Case and first case`

Comment: @Hibari - I have changed it.